# Navigation Properties Order Causes Serialization Failure

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, system.text.json

Can anybody explain this behavior so that I can manage it in the future?

I have a query (defined as  IQueryable) with a number of include statements.  I am using entityframework for an SQL Server database.

The primary entity and a few of the included entities have a foreign key to a code table that I used to define Time Period Types (Year, Month, Quarter, etc...) along with data related to each of these.

In the Period entity, I have navigation properties for the entities they provide values to.

After successfully running the query with its includes, I would serialize the results using system.text.json.

I started to get cycle errors with serialization despite setting the reference handler to "preserve".

After investigation, I found that serialization is successful or fails depending on the order of my includes in the code table entity.

So, if my entity includes navigation properties like this:

```
public IList<entity1>? entity1Collection { get; set; } = new List<entity1>();
public IList<entity2>? entity2Collection { get; set; } = new List<entity3>();
public IList<entity3>? entity3Collection { get; set; } = new List<entity3>();
public IList<entity4>? entity4Collection { get; set; } = new List<entity4>();
public IList<entity5>? entity5Collection { get; set; } = new List<entity5>();
```

Results:  Serialization works.

However, If I swap the order of the above navigations (by cutting pasting), serialization will fail because of the cycle error.

***Note:  The numbering scheme of my entities above are just for the purpose of this post and have not meaning.

Since I did not believe that the order mattered, I re-executed this from scratch repeatedly and always achieved identical results -- I am confident that there are no other difference introduced.

Looking for help understanding this:

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. If it is, are there rules/guidelines I should be following when defining the order of navigation properties in my entities?

here is the error:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path:

And, yes, it is a `MaxDepth` issue.

Comment: Hard to say without a [mcve].  If you can't share a one, could you at least share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback an inner exception(s) if any?

Comment: Also, are you sure you are getting an exception about **cycle errors**?  Could you be getting an exception about exceeding [`JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.maxdepth)?  It's quite possible to increase or decrease the max serialization depth by modifying the order of properties.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.

I can't provide a working example, but here is the error:

System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: 

And, yes, it is a "MaxDepth" issue.

Comment: And, here is how I am recreating (of course, the real entity names have meaningful names).   Swapping out which of these are commented and which are active results in either serialization success or failure:

Comment: This one fails:


//Generated Origial Order – Produces Max Depth Error
public IList<Entity1>? nvEntity1Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity1>();
public IList<Entity2>? nvEntity2Collection { get; set; } = new List< Entity2>();
public IList<Entity3>? nvEntity3Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity3>();
public IList<Entity4>? nvEntity4Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity4>();
public IList<Entity5>? nvEntity5Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity5>();

Comment: This one works:

////Generated Same Order as Backup – Serializes Successfully
//public IList<Entity5>? nvEntity5Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity5>();
//public IList<Entity3>? nvEntity3Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity3>();
//public IList<Entity2>? nvEntity2Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity2>();
//public IList<Entity4>? nvEntity4Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity4>();
//public IList<Entity1>? nvEntity1Collection { get; set; } = new List<Entity1>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Text.Json is a single-pass depth-first serializer.  When [reference preservation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references) is enabled, an object will be serialized the **first time** it is encountered.  Only the `"$ref": "N"` will be serialized on subsequent encounters.  Thus **if your serialization graph is sufficiently deep**, changing the property order could lead to [`MaxDepth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.maxdepth?view=net-7.0) being exceeded.

For example, consider the following model, which contains a list of parents and a list of all children.  Parents have children, and children have friends:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<Child> AllChildren { get; set; }= new();
    public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }= new();
}

public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Child
{
    public List<Child> Friends { get; set; } = new ();
}
```

If I construct an instance with 2 parents and 2 children, where each child is a friend:

```
var child1 = new Child { };
var child2 = new Child { Friends = { child1 } };
child1.Friends.Add(child2);

var model = new TModel
{
    AllChildren = { child1, child2 },
    Parents = { new Parent { Children = { child1 } }, new Parent { Children = { child2 } } },
};
```

Then the model will serialize successfully at `MaxDepth = 10` and fail at `MaxDepth = 9`.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y7F6DZ).

Now imagine I modify `Model` to serialize the parents first:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }= new();
    public List<Child> AllChildren { get; set; }= new();
}
```

Then **serialization will fail at `MaxDepth` 10, 11 and 12**.  It will only serialize successfully starting at `MaxDepth = 13`.  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VqhSDl).

The cause of the difference is the previously mentioned depth-first serialization.  In the first version, the second child is serialized as a friend of the first inside the `AllChildren` list:

```json
{
  "$id": "1",
  "AllChildren": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "Friends": {
          "$id": "4",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$id": "5",
              "Friends": {
                "$id": "6", // Here is where the second child is serialized.
                "$values": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "3"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$ref": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Parents": {
    "$id": "7",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "8",
        "Children": {
          "$id": "9",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$ref": "3"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$id": "10",
        "Children": {
          "$id": "11",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$ref": "5"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But in the second version, the second child is serialized inside the `Parents` list, leading to the increased max depth:

```json
Testing MaxDepth = 13:
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Parents": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "Children": {
          "$id": "4",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$id": "5",
              "Friends": {
                "$id": "6",
                "$values": [
                  {
                    "$id": "7",
                    "Friends": {
                      "$id": "8", // Here is where the second child is serialized.  Notice it's deeper in the graph.
                      "$values": [
                        {
                          "$ref": "5" 
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$id": "9",
        "Children": {
          "$id": "10",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$ref": "7"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "AllChildren": {
    "$id": "11",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$ref": "5"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "7"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**To prevent this**, you may apply [`JsonPropertyOrderAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertyorderattribute) to your properties to force children to be serialized before parents:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]
    public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }= new();
    [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
    public List<Child> AllChildren { get; set; }= new();
}
```

If you do, serialization will no longer depend on C# property order.  Demo #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KlfDZ8).

Comment: Thanks to all, and particularly to dbc for that greatly appreciated answer.

I was able to apply the [JsonPropertyOrder(x)] attribute to my code and have verified that it works.